# Email Template HTML WYSIWYG does not load

Tags: civimail, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am running on the latest version of CiviCRM, 5.17, and when I go into CiviMail to create an email message the HTML wysiwyg editor does not load. I get a console error saying
`CRM.wysiwyg._create is not a function`

If I put a debugger right before the line I can see the the CRM.wysiwyg object does not have ._create method but it does have a .create() method.  If I change the code to use the .create() method then it seems to loop for ever and the tab stops responding.

I had this issue on the previous version of civicrm, 5.13, which is why I tried the upgrade to 5.17.

There is a message during upgrade about updating the templates but when I click the link for more info it take me to a page saying the documents have moved.

I do have the ckEditor enabled on the site.

I am running on wordpress 5.0.4.
I did reset the cache and clear the templates_c folder but neither cured it.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Tried in another browser? Ad-blocker enabled?

Comment: Can you check resource url?

Comment: I did clear the cache and the templates_c folder.  I have tried on multiple browser and is always the same error.  I dont have an ad-blocker enabled.

Comment: As for the resource urls they are all set. I dont see any other errors in the web console.  It seems the API for wysiwyg is not the same for some reason.  Any suggestions on where to look for ideas?

Comment: I have made some more progress on this issue.  I found that my theme was redirecting 404s to the login page.  Once I disabled that then I was able to find that I am getting a 404 loading crm.ckeditor.  I found the reference in `Core/resources.php` It seems the file is looking to be loaded from `"[civicrm.root]/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js`.   In my settings file I have civicrm_root pointing to the base directory in `/var/www....`  So it tries to load that file as the URL with the /var/www in the URL.  If I hard code that reference to the file location it works.  Is there a relative var I can use

Comment: what does your civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1 have defined in resource URL?

Comment: That link does not specifically work. The WP link is wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Furl&reset=1 so that might be part of the issue I suppose.   

The Resource Url itself has: wp-content/plugins/civicrm/